# Как дополнительно передать переменные в шаблон через django?

Tags: django, переменные, шаблоны

Сразу извиняюсь если выражаюсь немного не правильно. Я новичок :D

У меня есть view:

```
class TaskListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = TodoItem
    context_object_name = "tasks"
    template_name = "tasks/list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        u = self.request.user
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(owner=u)
```

Он добавляет объект в мой html. Но и вместе с этим мне нужно добавить пару переменных туда. Я не знаю как, через "*render*" не получится. А может и получится но я не знаю как этот объединить, помогите пожалуйста, я уже в тупике.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class TaskListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
model = TodoItem
context_object_name = "tasks"
template_name = "tasks/list.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['book_list'] = Book.objects.all()
        return context
```

В шаблоне:

```
{{ book_list }}
```

Если это не один объект, а несколько то в шаблоне примерно так:

```
{% for book in book_list %}
    <p>{{ book }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Почитать про это можно здесь: https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display.html#adding-extra-context

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Всё перерыл, но почему то не смог найти в интернете про подобную функцию)

Answer (score 0):

```
args = {}
args['post'] = "То, что нужно передать"
return render(request, 'шаблон, куда нужно передать', args)
```

В шаблоне

```
{{post}}
```

Comment: А куда прописывать? В новую функцию? Потому что у меня класс построенный на class-based views. Я попробовал создать функцию в классе, но никаких результатов